# How can i integrate google location view and street view map

Tags: javascript

i able to integrate google street view and google location view map in my application separately.But now i need to map view integrate in one view.
google location marker and street marker at present in location view.I am unable to do that.can any one give me the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Md. Shahjalal, take a look on this library: https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples.html